# Yocto esdk cannot find header file and static lib

Tags: linux, eclipse, sdk, yocto, autotools

I am trying to add SOEM library to my image and develop application with library.
Here is my recipe:

```
LICENSE = "Unknown"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=9e0f3a6879e76ac16053729f3b05a2d4"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/OpenEtherCATsociety/SOEM.git;protocol=https"

# Modify these as desired
PV = "0.1+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "09d48acc328083f98a3652629ccf716bd5d84444"

BBCLASSEXTEND =+ "native nativesdk"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit cmake

# Specify any options you want to pass to cmake using EXTRA_OECMAKE:
EXTRA_OECMAKE = ""
```

I added theses lines to my local.conf:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " soem"

TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " nativesdk-soem"
```

I can find Header and lib files at directory:

> build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/soem/0.1+gitAUTOINC+09d48acc32-r0/image/usr

after installed sdk and succesfuly integrated to eclipse i cannot include header files and library.

What should i check for succesfully include header files and library?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe add nativesdk-soem-dev ?

Comment: I added still no change. when i cross-compiled source code from terminal which has environment variables from sdk, succesfully get output. But no change from Eclipse side